# Append Data to a specific line number using SED/AWK in Unix

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file separated by colons that looks like this..

`StudentID:LastName:FirstName:
 0962344:Bob:Billy:
 0123456:Joe:Black:
 0987654:Jess:Foo:`

The first line will always contain the header. Let's say each field after the 3rd in all rows will contain grades.

Let's say I add hw1 to **only** Joe Black since he completed it early.

`StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw1:
 0962344:Bob:Billy::
 0123456:Joe:Black:100:
 0987654:Jess:Foo::`

First Question)

How would I append to the end of the a line when I have the line number to certain lines, or append to all lines but with different data (colons, the grade, or the assignment as above)?

Second Question)

How would I add data into those newly created fields for the other students. Add the grade for hw1 for Bob and Jess if there are more grades in the file. ex..

`StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw1:hw2:
 0962344:Bob:Billy:HOW DO I ADD HERE:50:
 0123456:Joe:Black:100:50:
 0987654:Jess:Foo:AND HERE:50:`

I'm assuming I can only use Awk since sed will go through every line.

Comment: In your example data the headers are sorted LastName FirstName, and the actual records are FirstName LastName. I will switch the First- and Last name in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gawk

question 1:

```
 awk -F':' -vOFS=':' '{NF+=1}NR==1{$(NF-1)="hw1"}/Joe/{$(NF-1)=100}1' file
StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw1:
 0962344:Bob:Billy::
 0123456:Joe:Black:100:
 0987654:Jess:Foo::
```

question 2:

```
awk -F':' -vOFS=':' 'NR==1{for(i=0;++i<=NF;)if($i=="hw1")l=i}/Bob/{$l="Your Num"}/Jess/{$l="Your New Num"}1' file
StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw1:hw2:
 0962344:Bob:Billy:Your Num:50:
 0123456:Joe:Black:100:50:
 0987654:Jess:Foo:Your New Num:50:
```

Comment: How would I make this work if I where to enter a grade for each student, not only Joe. Would this work? `awk -F':' -vOFS=':' '{NF+=1}NR==1{$(NF-1)="$title"}/$fName/{$(NF-1)=$grade}1' file`

Comment: `awk -F':' -vOFS=':' -vg=$grade -vt=$title -vn="$f" '{NF+=1}NR==1{$(NF-1)=t}$2==n{$(NF-1)=g}1' file`

Comment: That would only print out the title `hw01,` and for `-vn="$f"`, did you mean `-vn=$fName`

Comment: `-vn="$f"` is name, such as  "Joe".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without awk. When data is stored in the  file input, you can loop over different lines with `while read -r fields; do .. done < input`. Using a colon as a fieldsep is done with `IFS=:`.
The logic within the loop can be edited (I would call a function), for avoiding to much nested if-statements I used a `continue` for the header line.

```
while IFS=: read -r StudentID FirstName LastName garbage; do
        if [ "$StudentID" = "StudentID" ]; then
                echo "StudentID:FirstName:LastName:hw1:"
                continue
        fi
        if [ "${FirstName}" = "Joe" ] && [ "${LastName}" = "Black" ] ; then
                echo "${StudentID}:${FirstName}:${LastName}:100:"
        else
                echo "${StudentID}:${FirstName}:${LastName}::"
        fi
done < input > input2
```

I wrote the output to input2, since that wil be the input for question 2.
Just for the fun of calculating a gave Billy the value 100 / 4. Jess is lucky, he gets 100 !

```
while IFS=: read -r StudentID FirstName LastName hw1 garbage; do
        if [ "$StudentID" = "StudentID" ]; then
                echo "StudentID:FirstName:LastName:hw1:hw2:"
                continue
        fi
        if [ "${FirstName}" = "Bob" ] && [ "${LastName}" = "Billy" ] ; then
                (( newnumber = 100 / 4 ))
                echo "${StudentID}:${FirstName}:${LastName}:${newnumber}:50:"
        elif [ "${FirstName}" = "Not" ] && [ "${LastName}" = "Existing" ] ; then
                echo "${StudentID}:${FirstName}:${LastName}:77:50:"
        elif [ -n "${hw1}" ]; then
                echo "${StudentID}:${FirstName}:${LastName}:${hw1}:50:"
        else
                echo "${StudentID}:${FirstName}:${LastName}:100:50:"
        fi
done < input2
```

Comment: I got the first part down, but I am  having trouble with the second part. I need to make a function that can insert data into ANY field where the header field matches. (Insert a grade into header field 4 where student is Jess). Keep in mind that I can still enter in new grades for any student. I just can't enter in a grade for an existing assignment.

Comment: Look how Bob Billy is assigned the rate ${newnumber}.